# How to take xml file of running instances in openstack?

Tags: instance, openstack, libvirt, openstack-nova

Im trying to edit xml file of running instances in openstack but couldn't able to find out where it is placed .

When i tried with #virsh list -all

Which is listing some vms which is not created via openstack

Please someone help me out to take xml of running instances in openstack.

Comment: Is your question related to the VMS family of operating systems, e.g. OpenVMS? That is what the [`vms`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) tag means. (From the tag description: "Note: This tag should not, as a rule, be used for Virtual Machines (VMs).")

Answer (score 1):

There are several different libvirt instances, and `virsh` will auto-detect a connection. If you run  `virsh`  as root it'll connect to `qemu:///system` while if you run it as non-root it'll connect to `qemu:///session`. OpenStack / Nova will be using `qemu:///system`. If you want to make this explicit tell `virsh` which to use  `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all` should show you the VMs.

A further complication is that some deployments of OpenStack will put libvirt and QEMU inside a container, so if you run `virsh` in your host, it won't be able to access the libvirt/QEMU inside the container. You would need to find which container its using, enter the container namespaces, and then run `virsh` inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

You also should consider that openstack nova assembles the resulting xml file from its database from [multiple sources](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/LibvirtXMLConfigAPIs). So even if you edit the final xml file on the hypervisor your VM will lose the changes after restart (if it even starts with those changes). You need to find the properties you want to change and edit the respective nova.conf settings, image properties and so on.